# What are wildcard certificate limitations in SAN extension?

Tags: tls, certificates

Consider following example:

We created own CA certificate (self-signed) and imported into browser trust store.
We signed certificate by this CA certificate with SAN extension with following domains:

- DNS: *.dev
- DNS: *.*.dev

No matter if CN is present in certificate or even whole DN is missing.
Still getting following errors in browsers when accessing domain **https://test.dev**:

Firefox 45.8.0:

```
test.dev uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.dev, *.*.dev Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit):

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

There is only one working wildcard in SAN for third level domain, when browsers accepts connection:

- DNS: *.secondlevel.dev

Multilevel wildcard in SAN is not accepted by browsers:

- DNS: *.*.secondlevel.dev

Is there a way to have multilevel wildcard in SAN extension or what are limitations for wildcards in SAN extensions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#page-27):

> The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
> which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
> left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net).

Thus, wildcard is only allowed in the left-most label which automatically restricts it to at most one level of wildcard.

A similar restriction can also be found in the [CA/Browser Forum
Baseline Requirements 1.4.2](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.4.2.pdf) which combined with other definitions in the document restricts the wildcard to only the left-most label:

> Wildcard Certificate:
>      A   Certificate containing  an  asterisk    (*) in  the left‐most   position    of  any of  the Subject
> Fully‐Qualified Domain  Names   contained   in  the Certificate.

Apart from that the CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements have more restrictions which result in `*.dev` not working since `dev` is in the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat):

> CAs   SHALL   revoke  any certificate where   wildcard    character   occurs  in  the first   label   position    immediately to  the left    of  a   “registry‐controlled”   label   or  “public
> suffix”.

For more information see section "3.2.2.6 Wildcard Domain Validation" of the Baseline Requirements.

Comment: However it means *.dev should work as expected.

Comment: @ZZromanZZ: see update which explains why `*.dev` is not working.